# Windows service need to restart to detect uninstalled application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a code for windows service that reads installed applications in the system. When I upgrade or downgrade the version of a particular application , the service detects it on the next interval. However, If I uninstall an application from the device,the service can't detect it on the interval. I need to manually restart the service to detect that service is uninstalled.

What different thing happens while restarting the service that doesn't happen during interval hit?

**EDIT**

Here is the sample code

```
public partial class Scheduler : ServiceBase
{
        private Timer timer;
    public Scheduler()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer(900000);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Start();
    }

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                timer.Stop();
                 UpdateInfoForPID();//method to get installed applications

           }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            timer.Start();
        }
    }



protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer = null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you create a car and tell us that the car doesn't go forward,only go backwards , is it really possible for us to tell what's happening unless we really see how the car was built ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I have added the sample code. Can you please help me now?

Comment: Okay, now i can take a look bro

Comment: Not enough code though , i agree ur given code includes timer but i still don't know how `UpdateInfoForPID` looks like, right ?

Comment: Same UpdateInfoForPID is called during service restart and timer elapsed.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but are you maintaining a reference somewhere that's instantiated at service startup and not disposed properly at the end of UpdateInfoForPID() ? Without seeing the code on how UpdateInfoForPID() works, I can't really help you. Sorry :(